# How to configure typescript in a project with linked local package

Tags: typescript, npm, types, npm-link

I am working on a project that is linked to some other local project like this:

```js
{
  "name": "lib-a",
  dependencies: {
     "lib-b": "file:../../lib-b"
  }
}
```

The issue is that `lib-b` has some uncompiled module in its `node_modules`, and when I run `tsc` (from within lib-a) I get errors like this:

```
../node_modules/someLib/src/render.tsx:1:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import React from 'react';
```

I do have the types for `react` in `lib-a`'s node_modules, but the issue is that `lib-b`  has its own `node_modules` (outside of `lib-a`'s tree) and typescript tries to search for `react` there. Is there any way to tell typescript to search for the types in the root's node_modules as well??

here is the project hierarchy:

```
gitProjects
|_ lib-a <-- running tsc from here
|   |_ node_modules
|      |_ react
|      |_ lib-b (symlink)
|_ lib-b
    |_ node_modules
       |_ some-uncompiled-lib (that tries to use react)
```

Note that I am not using a mono-repo (I can't use a monorepo). I am running tsc from within `lib-a`. when installing `lib-b` properly (using the published version), everything works. Only when I am using local dependency things starts to fail.
Is there any way around it?